# По какой логике задается условие?

Tags: математика, геометрия

**Задача**: Дана точка А(х, у). Определить, принадлежит ли она треугольнику с вершинами в точках (х1, у1), (х2,у2), (х3,у3).

**Решение**:

```
uses crt;

var x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,tx,ty:real;
begin
clrscr;
writeln('Введите координаты вершин треугольника по часовой стрелке:');
readln(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);
writeln('Введите координаты точки:');
readln(tx,ty);
if((tx-x1)*(y1-y2)-(ty-y1)*(x1-x2)>=0)
and((tx-x2)*(y2-y3)-(ty-y2)*(x2-x3)>=0)
and((tx-x3)*(y3-y1)-(ty-y3)*(x3-x1)>=0) then
write('Лежит') else write('Не лежит');
readln
end.
```

Comment: Pascal и if абсолютно ни при чём, это обычная школьная формула

Answer (score 1):

Уравнение вида `(tx-x1)*(y1-y2)-(ty-y1)*(x1-x2) = 0` - это [уравнение прямой, проходящей через две точки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F#%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9,_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8) (по ссылке - второй вариант, просто уравнение домножено на знаменатели левой и правой части, а потом все перенесено в левую часть уравнения). Если равенство выполняется, то точка лежит на этой прямой.

Если заменить равенство на `>=`, то в зависимости от того, с какой стороны от прямой лежит точка, мы получим в результате истину или ложь.

В условии неравенства подобраны таким образом, что все три неравенства одновременно выполняются только тогда, когда точка находится внутри треугольника.